# Remove indentation and formatting from outerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove the html indentation/formatting from the outerHTML string below?

I know I could simply do some regex replacing (`/\s/`) in the string. However the html may contain a textarea or pre where `\t`, `\n` characters should be preserved.

Any idea how I can remove the html indentation?

```
var htmlToPostBack = $(target).prop('outerHTML');  
// sometimes this string can contain formatted html, for eg....

<section>
   <div>...</div>
</section>

// I want to remove the indentation/formatting to get...
<section><div>...</div></section>
```

Comment: Maybe `.trim()` is what you want? What is `target`?

Comment: You say that you want to preserve the new line `\n` but then in your example output you've just removed it. Do you want all tags to be in the same line or do you want to literally just remove the indentation, in your example that would be 3 lines and would just move the `div` to the left.